# How to overwrite mutable string inside a loop?

Tags: rust

My example is slightly modified from [the guessing game tutorial in The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html).

After the first iteration, the loop does not appear to read in the user input to the mutable string correctly.

Can you please identify what is wrong in the below code with regards to `mut input_text`?

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let random_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 51);
    let mut input_text = String::new(); // Works fine if allocated inside loop
    loop {
        println!("Enter your guess:");
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input_text)
            .expect("Failed to read input");

        let input_number: u32 = match input_text.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        println!(
            "You entered {} which converted to u32 is {}",
            input_text, input_number
        );

        match input_number.cmp(&random_number) {
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Input > Random"),
            Ordering::Less => println!("Input < Random"),
            Ordering::Equal => println!("Input == Random"),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time you call `read_line`, you _append_ to the existing string. Try calling [`input_text.clear()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.clear) before reading.

Comment: The easiest solution is actually to move the declarationg of `input_text` inside the loop. You noticed yourself that this makes your code work, and the additional allocation really doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Thank you @Jmb. I should've looked up the API doc [https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line]. From the API name, it seemed like it would just overwrite.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, the repeated allocation probably doesn't mater in this example. But surely, we don't want to do it in non-trivial programs when the memory usage is higher?

Answer (score 2):

As @Jmb mentioned in the comments, `read_line` doesn't overwrite the String but appends to it. If you'd like to overwrite the String you have to first call `clear` on it like so:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let random_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 51);
    let mut input_text = String::new();
    loop {
        println!("Enter your guess:");

        // clear input_text from previous loop iteration
        input_text.clear();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input_text)
            .expect("Failed to read input");

        let input_number: u32 = match input_text.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        println!(
            "You entered {} which converted to u32 is {}",
            input_text.trim(), input_number
        );

        match input_number.cmp(&random_number) {
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Input > Random"),
            Ordering::Less => println!("Input < Random"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("Input == Random");
                break; // break on win condition
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Also your program was an infinite loop so I added a `break` on the win condition.